# MVVM Light DataGrid DeleteCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, mvvm-light

short structure of my project is (using MVVM Light Toolkit):

- View (UserControl) with DataGrid
- ViewModel
- DataAccess with    ValueObjects
- DB

I'm using an ObservableCollection for DataBinding to my DataGrid,
but I stuck at removing a Row in Datagrid and save it to DataBase.

In older projects I used CommandManager.PreviewExecuted event from System.Windows.Input and there I checked event args for the DataGrid.DeleteCommand. Simply this:

```
if(e.Command == DataGrid.DeleteCommand)
{
    DataAccessContext.Sample.DeleteOnSubmit(data);
    DataAccessContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I've googled for a few hours now but don't get the right way.
I tried to use PassEventArgsToCommand, but the Event DataGrid.DeleteCommand or CommandManager.PreviewExecuted is not firing, SelectionChangedCommand works well, but I don't know how to check it for the important DataGrid.DeleteCommand.

Here's my xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="391" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" Margin="2,0,0,0" RowEditEnding="dataGrid1_RowEditEnding" CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand
                                Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand,Mode=OneWay}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,ElementName=dataGrid1}">
                                </cmd:EventToCommand>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="DataGrid.DeleteCommand"> //I've also tried PreviewExecuted and CommandManager.PreviewExecuted as EventName
                                <cmd:EventToCommand
                                    Command="{Binding SelectedItems,Mode=OneWay}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ExecutedRoutedEventArgs, ElementName=dataGrid1}"
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                    ></cmd:EventToCommand>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vorname" Binding="{Binding Surname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Thanks for your answers and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the delete on the DataGrid and instead hook up the Delete key to a command (via KeyBinding) which will do your saving and remove the row from the source collection.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412743/how-to-bind-delete-action-in-wpf-datagrid-to-a-command-or-property-in-view-mod).