# WPF ListBox select next item after deletion with ICommand

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, listbox

This question evolves kind of the same issue like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963575/wpf-datagrid-lost-focus-after-row-delete), but it concerns a different problem that I face because I use bindings.

I have added a button to delete the currently selected item from a `ListBox` (and one for a `DataGrid` where the same problem arises). The code to do that is bound to the button via an `ICommand`-object and the `Button.Command` property:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteRowCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

However this means that the click action is directly funneled into the ViewModel, which of course does not know the view's `ListBox`, so it cannot notify the view or update any selection.

What is the proper way to trigger code-behind both in the viewmodel *and* the view?

Maybe I could use the command-property and a `Handles` statement, but I'm not sure if that's viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Path=Category, Mode=OneTime}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fields}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}" />
```

Code behind in `CategoryViewModel`, the class of the `Category` object from th data context:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Fields As ObservableCollection(Of FieldViewModel)
  Get
    Return m_Fields
  End Get
End Property
Private ReadOnly m_Fields As New ObservableCollection(Of FieldViewModel)

Public Property SelectedIndex As Integer
  Get
    Return m_SelectedIndex
  End Get
  Set(value As Integer)
    m_SelectedIndex = value
    ValidateSelectedIndex()
    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex")
    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem")
  End Set
End Property
Private m_SelectedIndex As Integer = -1

Public ReadOnly Property SelectedItem As FieldViewModel
  Get
    Return If(m_SelectedIndex = -1, Nothing, m_Fields.Item(m_SelectedIndex))
  End Get
End Property

Private Sub ValidateSelectedIndex()
  Dim count = m_Fields.Count
  Dim newIndex As Integer = m_SelectedIndex

  If count = 0 Then
    ' No Items => no selections
    newIndex = -1
  ElseIf count <= m_SelectedIndex Then
    ' Index > max index => correction
    newIndex = count - 1
  ElseIf m_SelectedIndex < 0 Then
    ' Index < min index => correction
    newIndex = 0
  End If

  m_SelectedIndex = newIndex
  RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex")
  RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem")
End Sub

Public Sub New(model As Category)
  ' [...] Initialising of the view model,
  ' especially the m_Fields collection

  ' Auto update of SelectedIndex after modification
  AddHandler m_Fields.CollectionChanged, Sub() ValidateSelectedIndex()
  ' Set the SelectedIndex to 0 if there are items
  ' or -1 if there are none
  ValidateSelectedIndex()
End Sub
```

Now, whenever you delete an item from the `m_Fields` collection, the `SelectedItem` will be changed to the next item, or the previous item if the last item was removed, or `Nothing` if the last remaining item was removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

Create a property in your ViewModel which will hold the SelectedItem.

```
private YourTypeHere _SelectedThing;

public YourTypeHere SelectedThing 
{
   get { return _SelectedThing; }
   set 
   { 
      _SelectedThing = value;

      //Call INotifyPropertyChanged stuff
    }
}
```

Now, bind your SelectedItem for your List to this property:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing}" ... />
```

Performing these actions means that your `SelectedThing` is now the responsibility of the ViewModel, and when you call the Delete command, you can simply **update the SelectedThing property to the last item in the list** and your ListBox will be automatically updated.

Comment: That is actually a pretty decent way to handle it. I will try to implement my view/viewmodel with that approach and tell you if I face any difficulties. If not, I will also mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: I had a little struggle, but the approach was the way to go. I will post the full solution later.