# WPF DataGrid loses focus after row delete / cut

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` implemented in an MVVM/Prism application.  The `DataGrid` supports Cut/Copy/Paste/Delete through a context menu and keyboard gestures.

I find that when a row is deleted/cut the entire `DataGrid` loses focus and keyboard focus moves to the last focused control.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

After removing a row I may want to re-paste into the `DataGrid`.  Furthermore if the grid is empty there is no way at all for it to get keyboard focus.  Clicking an empty grid does not give it focus.

Here is a similar question, but it doesn't solve the issue for me:
[DataGrid Looses Focus When Delete Key is Pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991188/datagrid-looses-focus-when-delete-key-is-pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the DataGrids Focus in the PreviewKeyDown-Event

```
private void TheDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
       var grid = (DataGrid)sender;
       FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(Window.GetWindow(grid), grid); //not tested
    }
}
```

If you dont want to put code in code-behind use [AttachedProperties](http://www.wpftutorial.net/AttachedProperties.html) in combination with the [DependencyPropertyChanged-Event](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/05/listening-to-dependencyproperty-changes.aspx).
[How to set set focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes... this works well, Thanks.

I find that I must handle Delete and Ctrl-X.  Also, I'm forcing focus on MouseDown (for focusing an empty grid) and ContextMenuClosing (for focusing after clicking Cut/Delete).

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon. PreviewKeyDown has the unfortunate side-effect of being called when editing a cell.  In those cases it steals Focus from the cell.  I found that setting focus in UnloadingRow instead works well.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution might be to handle the `LostFocus` event exposed by `DataGrid` and set focus on the control.

It arguably marginally infringes on the MVVM pattern i.e keeping the view dumb as hell, but it's still view code.

Comment: How would you propose distinguishing between user clicked outside of DataGrid type-of-lost-focus and the one when something was deleted?