# Datagrid loses keyboard focus when deleting an item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have found some similar questions, but none have fully solved my problem, so I have put together a small example.

I want to be able to press the D key, and delete that item from the ObservableCollection. This works as expected.

I then want to be able to continue maipulating the datagrid using the arrow keys and D key from the row after the one I just deleted (i.e. the index of the updated datagrid is equal to the index that the deleted item had).

The most useful answer I have found is this one - [Focus on DataGridCell for SelectedItem when DataGrid Receives Keyboard Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117281/focus-on-datagridcell-for-selecteditem-when-datagrid-receives-keyboard-focus/17127664#17127664) - however I'm not sure when I should be calling it as I want to call it after the view has been updated, I'm currently using the SelectionChanged event but obviously this is being called far too often to use.

Any advice would be much appreciated, I hope I have provided enough code below to enable anyone to recreate the project and replicate the problem.

Many Thanks,
Mike

My XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="D" Command="{Binding Delete}"/>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My view model:

```
namespace DataGridProblem
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems;
        private ICommand _delete;

        public MyItem SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public ICommand Delete { get { return _delete; } }
        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
        {
            get { return _myItems; }
            set
            {
                _myItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyItems");
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
            _myItems.Add(new MyItem() { name = "John" });
            _myItems.Add(new MyItem() { name = "Mike" });
            _myItems.Add(new MyItem() { name = "Phil" });

            _delete = new RelayCommand(DeleteSelected);
        }

        private void DeleteSelected(object obj)
        {
            MyItems.Remove(SelectedItem);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MyItem:

```
namespace DataGridProblem
{
    public class MyItem
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
private void DeleteSelected(object obj)
    {
        var index = MyItems.IndexOf(SelectedItem);
        MyItems.Remove(SelectedItem);
        if (MyItems.Count > 0)
           SelectedItem = MyItems[index >= MyItems.Count ? index-1 : index];
    }
```